# No matching function for call to 'Vector<Class::add()' method, class template dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic

I have a class Registration, that reads in the first line of input from a file and sends it to another class Result to read in the rest in a specific way. I want to achieve this using a custom vector class. I declare my Vector of Results in Registration as a private variable as follows:

```
Vector<Result> results;
```

This is how I use it in Registration.cpp:

```
void Registration::readFile(istream &input){

    long studentid1;
    unsigned semester1;


    input >> studentid1 >> semester1 >> count;



    SetStudentID(studentid1);
    SetSemester(semester1);


    for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++){

        results.add(&input); //sending the rest of the input to my dynamic array of Results
    }

}
```

I'm getting the error: `no matching function for call to 'Vector<Result>::add(std::istream*)'|` at the line `results.add(&input)` in Registration.cpp.

My Vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(int size = 10);
        ~Vector();

        void initialize(unsigned from = 0);
        void expand();
        void add(const T &obj);
        int size() const{return this->nrofel;}

        T& operator[](const int index);
        const T& operator[](const int index) const;


    private:
        T **data;
        unsigned capacity;
        unsigned nrofel;

};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size){

    this->capacity = size;
    this->nrofel = 0;
    this->data = new T*[this->capacity];

    this->initialize();

}

template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index){

    if(index < 0 || index > this->nrofel){

        throw ("Bad index");

    }

    return *this->data[index];

}

template <class T>
const T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index) const{

    if(index < 0 || index > this->nrofel){

        throw ("Bad index");

    }

    return *this->data[index];

}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::initialize(unsigned from){

    for(size_t i = from; i < this->capacity; i++){

        this->data[i] = nullptr;

    }

}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector(){

    for(size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++){

        delete this->data[i];

    }
    delete[]this->data;
}


template <class T>
void Vector<T>::expand(){

    this->capacity *= 2;

    T** tempData = new T*[this->capacity];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->nrofel; i++){

        tempData[i] = new T(*this->data[i]);

    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->nrofel; i++){

       delete this->data[i];

    }

    delete[] data;

    this->data = tempData;

    this->initialize(this->nrofel);

}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::add(const T &obj){

    if(this->nrofel >= this->capacity){

        this->expand();

    }

    this->data[this->nrofel++] = new T(obj);

}



#endif // VECTOR_H
```

Comment: If `results` contains type `Result`, and `add` takes in `Result` object (from `T`), why would passing in a pointer to an `istream` work? That's what the error is telling you. `add` expects a `Result` object.

Comment: I see what you mean. How would I be able to read in an istream then as I'm quite confused how to go about it? My goal is to get it to read the file input the way my Class Result is designed to, into a dynamic array of type Vector<Result>.

Comment: You create `Result` objects from the stream, and pass those into the `add` method.